# Undefined Variable in Class Lambda Function

Tags: python, tf.keras

When in the IDE I get the error:

```
"normalization_layer" is not defined
```

I tried the following code

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

normalization_layer = layers.Rescaling(1./255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixel values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
```

I have tried running it but it doesn't work in runtime. It works though when that code is not contained in a class. It is supposed to rescale a given image into the given range ([Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#standardize_the_data)) and works before I began merging my code into a class. This replicates the documentation and tutorials provided, and worked previously as in today before putting it inside of a class.

Comment: because class bodies *don't create enclosing scopes!* This is why you have to use `self.some_method` instead of just `some_method`!

Comment: The code you have here probably shouldn't go in a class body to begin with! It should be separated out into methods

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [mre] required. that code (_that_ code) could not have produced the error.

Answer (score 0):

You call layers() which is a method of Keras utility:

```
normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
```

let me know if this fixes your issue--when running just:

```
normalization_layer = layers.Rescaling(1./255)
```

the error message should be:

```
NameError: name 'layers' is not defined
```

so, I am not sure if I'm missing something. I ran the documentation example as given and it ran without error for me!